# Batch file nested for loop and if statements not running

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
::read in csv column 1 through 5
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=," %%A in (file.txt) do (
::look for file extension foo in the first column
    IF EXIST findstr ".foo" \%%A(
        do some stuff >> Z:\completed.txt ) ELSE (
::try to change into a directory
            cd /d %%A
::go through all foo files and do something with them
            for /d %%F in (dir *.foo) do (
                do some stuff >> Z:\completed.txt 
            ) )
)
```

When I run this, the ELSE is "unexpected". I'm sure batch has weird bracket processing, but Notepad++ seems to think they are all valid.

Comment: there's missing space after `%%A` in the `IF` condition, but `IF exist findstr ".foo"` is wrong.What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Tried it, not working. And also the code works without the else in there only with the if

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether a given path leads to a file or a folder of such files, and then do things with said files

Comment: FWIW `in (dir *.foo)` should be singlequoted: `in ('dir *.foo')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some wacked out pseudo code!

It is difficult to tell, but I think you are looking for something like:

```
>completed.txt (
  for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A in (file.txt) do (
    if /i "%%~xA" equ ".foo" (
      echo Doing stuff with %%A: a presumed file with .foo extension
    ) else pushd "%%~A" && (
      for %%F in (*.foo) do (
        echo Doing stuff with file %%F in folder %%A
      )
      popd
    )
  )
)
```

But the logic assumes that an extension of .foo implies a file, which may or may not be true.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Comments within bracketed code blocks.](http://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)

Avoid of using `:labels` and `:: labe-like comments` within a bracketed code block or `FOR` command. Always use `rem` instead of `::`.

**Proof**: a simple script (anyone could give a more sophisticated example):

```
==>type labels.bat
@ECHO %1>NUL
if ""=="" (
  rem comment
  @echo a rem comment precedes this echo command
)
if ""=="" (
  :: comment
  @echo a label-like comment precedes this echo command
)
if ""=="" (
  :label
  @echo a label precedes this echo command
)
if "" == "" (@echo a simple echo, no comments)
@goto :eof

==>labels.bat off
a rem comment precedes this echo command
'@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
a simple echo, no comments

==>
```

However, hard to understand your aim...